# Regex match all punctuations except 'D.C.'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that finds all punctuation marks [.!?] in order to capitalize the next word, however if the period is part of the string 'D.C.' it should be ignored, so far I have the first part working, but not sure about how to ignore 'D.C.'

`const punctuationCaps = /(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g;`

Comment: Just add `(?<!D\.C\.)` before `\s+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```js
var str = 'is D.C. a capital? i don\'t know about X.Y. stuff.';
var result = str.replace(/(^|[.!?](?<![A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.)\s+)([a-z])/g, (m, c1, c2) => { return c1 + c2.toUpperCase(); });
console.log('in:  '+str);
console.log('out: '+result);
```

Console output:

```
in:  is D.C. a capital? i don't know about X.Y. stuff.
out: Is D.C. a capital? I don't know about X.Y. stuff.
```

Explanation:

- `(^|[.!?])` - expect start of string, or a punctuation char
- `(?<![A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.)` - negative lookahead: but not a sequence of upper char and dot, repeated twice
- `\s+` - expect one or more whitespace chars
- all of the above is captured because of the parenthesis
- `([a-z])` - expect a lower case char, in parenthesis for second capture group

Answer (score 3):

You can match the `D.C.` part and use an alternation using the 2 capturing groups that you already have.

In the replacement check for one of the groups. If it is present, concatenate them making group 2 toUpperCase(), else return the match keeping D.C. in the string.

```js
const regex = /D\.C\.|(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g;
let s = "this it D.C. test. and? another test! it is.";
s = s.replace(regex, (m, g1, g2) => g2 ? g1 + g2.toUpperCase() : m);
console.log(s);
```